# How to classify based on percentage of observations in a column

Tags: sql

Need help thinking of the logic of how to approach this problem.

I have a SQL table which has some names with some accompanying information- for example- a company name accompanied by a region it has invested in.(there could be multiple investments in the same region) Each row represents the company and the region, therefore there can be multiple rows with the same region.  So there could be multiple rows for the same company. I’m trying to label the company based on its concentration of regions.

```
Column1   Column2
CompanyA  NYC
CompanyA  NYC
CompanyA  NYC
CompanyA  SF
CompanyA  SF
CompanyA  DC
```

I will then want to create a label for Company A based on its overall exposure. So if say 85% or more of its exposure is in one region, then I’d label it as say- “Concentrated”,
If less than 85% but more than 50% of its exposure is spread between 2 regions, then “Focused” else “Diversified”. I’d want an output of one row per company with the label I’ve assigned. I would have to do this in SQL, but any help with the logic or pseudo code will help me get started on how to think about this.

So my output should look like:

```
Column1   Column2
CompanyA  Focused
```

Comment: CompanyA seems concentrated, not focused.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't very clear on that.

Answer (score 3):

You want the percentage in the highest region to the overall all.  You can do this with two levels of aggregation and window functions:

```
select company,
       (case when max(cnt) >= 0.85 * sum(cnt)
             then 'focused'
             when sum(case when seqnum <= 2 then cnt end) >= 0.8 * sum(cnt)
             then 'concentrated'
             else 'diversified'
        end) as category
from (select company, region, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by company order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by company, region
     ) cr
group by company;
```

Comment: You seem to be both concentrated _and_ focused +1.

Comment: @Aamash . . . It is adding up the counts for the top two regions.

Comment: Thanks! Picking up your book to get better at this!